# Show uiviewcontroller from remote notification when app is quitted

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, apple-push-notifications

I'm trying to show a specific viewcontroller when I receive a remote push notification. I've added all of my code into the method `didReceiveRemoteNotification`:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userinfo: [NSObject: AnyObject])
```

I've added following code:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {
    let code = (userInfo["aps"] as! [String: AnyObject])
    // Call to retrieve blog
    if let blog = code["b"] as? NSNumber {
        let blogId = blog as! Int

        // Show blog from notification
        let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main",bundle: nil)
        var controller = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("blogCtrl") as! BlogController
        controller.blogId = blogId
        var rootController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("navCtrl1") as! UINavigationController
        self.window?.rootViewController = rootController
        rootController.pushViewController(controller, animated: true)
        self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    }
    if let tonic = code["t"] as? NSNumber {
        let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main",bundle: nil)
        var controller = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("tonicDetail") as! TonicDetailController
        controller.tonicId = tonic as! Int
        var rootController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("navCtrl1") as! UINavigationController
        self.window?.rootViewController = rootController
        rootController.pushViewController(controller, animated: true)
        self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    }
    if let gin = code["g"] as? NSNumber {
        let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main",bundle: nil)
        var controller = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("GinDetail") as! GinDetailController
        controller.ginId = gin as! Int
        var rootController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("navCtrl1") as! UINavigationController
        self.window?.rootViewController = rootController
        rootController.pushViewController(controller, animated: true)
        self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    }
}
```

When the app is in background everything works but when the app is quited, and I receive a remote notification it only starts up the application.
Is there a method which can be called if the application was quited before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*When your app launches after quitting the app, in the meanwhile you got remote notification, then `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` is first method in AppDelegate which fires on launching the app, check whether you have received any notification or not and  perform your operation accordingly.*

**You must look for this method in app delegate:-**

```
-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
```

**Now check whether your app has received any push notification or not**

```
UILocalNotification *notification = [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey];
    if (notification) {
        NSLog(@"app received a notification %@",notification);
        [self application:application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary*)notification];
    }else{
        NSLog(@"app did not receive a notification");
    }
```

Comment: In the first line of your code you're creating a UILocalNotification, but in the fourth line you're using it as a NSDictionary. Is this correct?

Because when i'm trying your code I've got an error: 
`var notification = launchOptions?[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey] as? UILocalNotification
        if notification != nil {
            println("There was a notification")
            self.application(application, didReceiveRemoteNotification: notification as! NSDictionary)}`
Error says: `NSDictionary is not implicitly convertible to [NSObject: AnyObject]]`

Comment: @HannesVandenBerghe instead of 'UILocalNotification' use 'NSDictionary' that will work

Comment: @Aanabidden this was indeed the solution! Thanks!